# Cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (loaderror) - Passenger / Apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, debian, passenger

Im having the follow error and cannot seem to figure out the reason why and how to fix it.

Setup

- Debian 8
- Ruby 2.2.2 (installed via RVM)
- RVM 1.26.11
- Rails 4.2.4
- Passenger 5.0.21
- Capistrano 3.4.0

### Passenger Error

```
    cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

### APP_NAME.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName HOSTNAME
    ServerAdmin sudo@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/APP_NAME/current/public
    PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21
    RailsEnv qa
    <Directory /var/www/APP_NAME/current/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Gem ENV

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - armv7l-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that [bundler](http://bundler.io/) is installed on your machine ?

I prefer rbenv to rvm and not 100% familiar on how to install bundler gem using RVM, but this [article](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler) might helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the article didnt solve the issue. I'll keep diggin...

Comment: i ended up reinstalling RVM, Bundle and Rails as  the "deploy" user i was using with capistrano. Might have been some sort of path issue in the apache directory. Thanks for your time and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error in my install, except it couldn't find the preloader, here was the problem.

I installed the passenger from apache-passenger installer and installed it from source that way, so it was up to date.

When I installed the gem I just used gem install passenger, which was not up to date. The missing file was in the older version, but not in the newer one so I ended up having to do
`rsync -av --ignore-existing /path/to/passenger-out-of-date-folder/ /path/to/passenger-up-to-date-folder/`